# Why is this React Component rendering first?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, next.js

I could use your input on a quick question about Component loads.

### The Goal

Return the `<Login />` Component if the user isn't logged in, and the App if they are.

### Expected Behavior

When a user is logged in, they see the App.

### Observed Behavior

The `<Login />` Component flickers (renders) for a moment, then the user sees the App.
*My goal is to eliminate this flicker!*

### Code Samples

#### Index.js

```
export default function Index() {

  let [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)

  const router = useRouter()

  // User object comes in from an Auth Context Provider
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext)
  const { email } = user

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      setIsLoading(false)
    }
  }, [])

  // Returns the App if logged in, login screen if not
  const getLoggedIn = () => {
    if (user.loggedIn) {
      return (
        <>
          // App goes here
        </>
      )
    } else {
      return <Login />
    }
  }

  return (
    <Box className="App">
      { isLoading
      ? <div className={classes.root}>
          <LinearProgress />
        </div>
      : getLoggedIn()
      }
    </Box>
  )
}
```

#### Auth Context

Note: I'm using Firebase for auth.

```
 // Listens to auth state changes when App mounts
  useEffect(() => {
    // Calls setUser state update method on callback
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChange(setUser)
    return () => {
      unsubscribe()
    }
  }, [])
  
  // Brings data from auth to Auth Context user state via callback
  const onAuthStateChange = callback => {
    return auth.onAuthStateChanged(async user => {
      if (user) {
        const userFirestoreDoc = await firestore.collection('users').doc(user.uid).get()
        const buildUser = await callback({ 
          loggedIn: true, 
          email: user.email, 
          currentUid: user.uid, 
          userDoc: userFirestoreDoc.data()
        })
      } else {
        callback({ loggedIn: false })
      }
    })
  }
```

#### Stack

```
"next": "^8.1.0",
"react": "^16.8.6",
"react-dom": "^16.8.6"
```

Thanks so much for taking a look.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem and resolved it by storing the user in local storage

then on app start up do this:

`const [user, setUser] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authUser')))`

and it'll use the details from localstorage and you wont see a flicker

(it's because onauthstate takes longer to kick in)

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I'm trying to avoid using local storage for user credentials for security reasons though. I think that you're right that it's because of the async call from the auth server.

Comment: I don't think storing anything locally is a problem as it'll all be client side anyway. so just store stuff locally that isn't sensitive. you could use `sessionStorage` too so that removes it on end of browser session

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out a sort of 'hacky' way around this. One needs to set the value of the boolean on which the initial load of the App depends...

```
const getLoggedIn = () => {
    // Right here
    if (user.loggedIn) {
      return (
        <>
          // App goes here
        </>
      )
    } else {
      return <Login />
    }
```

...*before* making any asynchronous calls in the AuthContext. Like this:

```
const onAuthStateChange = callback => {
    return auth.onAuthStateChanged(async user => {
      if (user) {
        // sets loggedIn to true to prevent flickering to login screen on load
        callback({ loggedIn: true })
        const userFirestoreDoc = await firestore.collection('users').doc(user.uid).get()
        const buildUser = await callback({ 
          loggedIn: true,
          email: user.email, 
          currentUid: user.uid, 
          userDoc: userFirestoreDoc.data()
        })
      } else {
        callback({ loggedIn: false })
      }
    })
  }
```

I hope this helps someone.